# Multiple forms on same page.. Solspace Freeform

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

When there's two forms on a single page. (E.g Newsletter Sign up and Book a Tour) The submit button obviously validates both forms.

How can I differentiate between them both and make them independent?

```
{{ craft.freeform.form("newsletter", {
    id: "form-newsletter"
    }
}).render() }}
```

The other form is loaded into the page through a template via a custom field.

Comment: I never used Freeform but I always use formbuilder but the issue I always come up with is one of the ID's being the same. Try to change that if you have them selected in a matrix block you can set the `block.id` behind all your id's

Comment: In the example above I had set the ID of the form to be unique but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this issue. We'll have a fix available for this in the next release of Freeform. :)

In the meantime, affected customers can [contact us for a patched copy](https://solspace.com/craft/create-ticket/freeform).